# C# Establish SQL Connection

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a small problem with my SQL Server and the connection I want to establish to it.

Here's my server:

[SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZziX.png)

Now I've tried to establish a connection, but it does not seem to work:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=Admin;" +
                                   "password=PleaseWork;server=SQLEXPRESS" +
                                   "connection timeout=1");
try
{
    myConnection.Open();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    catchExceptionBox.Text = e.ToString();
}
```

Unfortunately, since I have not yet worked with SQL Server, I do not know how to look up the IP of my server. Anyways, the error message I receive is a standard failed-connection message (which I receive after 14 seconds of trying to connect).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, if you don't know the IP of your server, that is likely your issue, isn't it? Also, "connection timeout=1" seems pretty low.

Comment: Try using "localhost\SQLEXPRESS" as your server.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot Well, I thought using the name would suffice... I changed the timeout to 30, but still no change. Using localhost\\SQLEXPRESS also brought no change

Comment: Check out @Valentin's answer. You have a missing semicolon.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot Yes, I saw it. Thank you very much^^

Answer (score 3):

A SQL Server connection string should be along the lines of:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

You are not specifying the database name. `myServerAddress` doesn't have to be the IP Address of your server and can be the name of your server instead.

[www.sqlconnectionstrings.com/sqlserver](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server)  is a good resource to use.

Comment: He is using SQL Server Express, so more like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#sse

Comment: @Ernesto: I missed that. Good spot.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Regarding the database, I have not yet set up one (except if it sets up one by standard, but then I wouldn't know the name).

Comment: You also might need to set Integrated Security=False;to use username password.

Comment: I think it is false by default. It is only switched on when you set it to true.

Comment: You are right. Assuming Admin is a user in SQL and after the missing semicolon, it should work as it is. If not, he could switch to USING integrated security and give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

Are you missing `;` after `server=SQLEXPRESS`?

Comment: That brought indeed a change! Now it's just a failed login. Thank you very much!!